# Bootstrap 3, row прижать к низу

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте, разбираюсь с bootstrap 3, вот пример:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class=row></div>
 <div class=row></div>
 <div class=row></div>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтоб нижний row был прилеплен к низу контейнера?
И еще, если задана высота контейнера, можно ли выровнять по высоте все внутренние row, чтоб высота rows была одинакова?

Comment: Обязательно на bootstrap?

Comment: @ldar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @kotik да. Если я проект реализую на bootstrap, то должен по максимум реализовывать его функции.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, можно. И это легко реализовать: **[посмотреть пример](http://www.bootply.com/mqCv5F8Vck)**

```
.container {
    height: 400px;
}
.container > .row {
    height: 33.3333%;
}
```

Comment: А на первый вопрос, есть ответ?
Чтоб row был прилеплен к низу, а верхние row размещались вверху, к примеру container высотой 600px, row шириной 100px, верхние два были прижаты к верху, нижний к низу и между ними был промежуток 300px

Comment: @ldar, нужен поясняющий схематичный рисунок, но сразу скажу, что у `bootstrap` нет нужных вам классов.